# How to shuffle the batches themselves in pytorch?

Tags: python, random, pytorch-dataloader

How to keep the sequences in each batch unshuffled, while shuffling the batches?

Inspired by the question asked [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pytorch/comments/iq5xqg/does_dataloadershuffletrue_shuffle_the/).

Comment: Can you please explain the utility of doing this?

Comment: Useful when dealing with time-correlated data (video footage) where you would want to share data between neighboring frames. I believe this should reduce overfitting as compared to a fully unshuffled dataset where the model can just learn the order.

Comment: In that case, each sequence forms a single observation object, not susceptible to shuffling.  Time-sequence models are already built to deal with this.  The question seems to ask how to reinvent this wheel.

Comment: Then, what is the better way to do this? When I set the DataLoader's shuffle argument to True, this shuffles all the data within the minibatches. Excuse my ignorance; I have only been learning PyTorch for half a year now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is not a direct answer to your question. I want to address an issue with the answer you posted yourself. In my opinion, doing the following, is a *very* bad idea:

```
dataloader = random.sample(list(dataloader), len(dataloader))
```

This defeats the whole purpose of creating a dataset and a data loader in the first place. Because as soon as you call `list(dataloader)` you end up compiling down your dataset into a single list of tensors. In other words, it will call `__getitem__` for each index in the dataset. A data loader is designer to load data batch by batch (or more depending on the number of workers) avoiding to load the entire dataset in memory at once.

This is even more important when working with images which requires image loading from the file system. This is critical and I believe you shouldn't be doing this at all.

Take a look here, with a dummy dataset:

```
class DS(Dataset):
    def __getitem__(self, _):
        return torch.rand(100)

    def __len__(self):
        return 10000

dl = DataLoader(DS(), batch_size=16)
x = list(dl)
```

Here `x` will contain *10,000* tensors of size *100*, which your computer can handle. Now imagine having a dataset made up of *10,000* *512x512* RGB images, you just can't hold that much in memory!

Futhermore, something I haven't even mentioned is data augmentation. Which is only possible when retaining a data loader (i.e. a generator). So the transformation are computed on the input data at runtime vs at *compile-time* (if you will) when using `list(dataloader)`.

---

I would instead suggest you make your `Dataset` generate that *unshuffled* sequence for each item, then make a `DataLoader` out of it with `shuffle=True`. This feels a lot more natural than generating a `DataLoader` only to compile it down. Use your dataset class as it's supposed to. It should be the one constructing each sequence (i.e. datapoint), or as [@Prune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4785185/prune) puts it a "single observation object".

Answer (score 0):

[bad answer - use [@Ivan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65555111/10084882) above]

1. Create a Dataset

```py
dataset = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] # Realistically use torch.utils.data.Dataset
```

2. Create a non-shuffled Dataloader

```py
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=False)
```

3. Cast the dataloader to a `list` and use `random`'s `sample()` function

```py
import random
dataloader = random.sample(list(dataloader), len(dataloader))
```

There is probably a better way to do this using a custom batch sampler or something but it was too confusing to figure out for me, so the above method seems to work well.